# Транспонировать представление

Tags: sql, postgresql

Получаю такое представление

| Категория | Период | Количество |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | март 2023 | 100 |
| 1 | апрель 2023 | 200 |
| 2 | март 2023 | 130 |
| 2 | апрель 2023 | 99 |

количество и прочее получаю агрегирующими функциями с группировками, условно:

```
SELECT Категория, Период, COUNT(что надо посчитать) AS Количество
FROM Таблица
GROUP BY Категория, Период
```

на самом деле я хочу получить данные в таком виде

| Период | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| март 2023 | 100 | 130 |
| апрель 2023 | 200 | 99 |

Как это можно получить запросом? Можно конечно сделать скрипт, чтобы создавал новую таблицу, и через INSERT вставлял значения из представления, но может можно прям сразу запросом получить?
БД PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо.
Нашел еще такой вариант

```
SELECT
    Период,
    count(то что надо посчитать) FILTER(WHERE Категория = 1) AS Category_1,
    count(то что надо посчитать) FILTER(WHERE Категория = 2) AS Category_2
FROM Таблица
GROUP BY Период;
```

Выдало то что надо

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы получить данные в таком виде, можно воспользоваться функцией `crosstab` из расширения `tablefunc`. Пример запроса:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
  'SELECT Период, Категория, COUNT(что надо посчитать) AS Количество
   FROM Таблица
   GROUP BY Период, Категория
   ORDER BY Период, Категория',
  'SELECT DISTINCT Категория FROM Таблица ORDER BY Категория'
) AS ct("Период" TEXT, "1" INT, "2" INT);
```

В этом запросе сначала группируем данные по категориям и периодам, затем используем функцию `crosstab`, чтобы перевернуть таблицу. Первый аргумент функции - это исходный запрос, второй - запрос, который возвращает список всех категорий. **Результат будет иметь тот же формат, что вы кинули.**

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  Период,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Категория = 1 THEN что надо посчитать END) AS "1",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Категория = 2 THEN что надо посчитать END) AS "2"
FROM Таблица
GROUP BY Период
```

На примере столбца `"1"`. Если условие `Категория = 1` не выполнено, то результат выражения `CASE … END` будет `NULL`, и `COUNT` эту строку проигнорирует.